# Job history server in Hadoop 2.7.1 is not working

Tags: java, hadoop, configuration

I explored everywhere but could not get the solution. When I do run `jps` command it does not show job history server running.

What are configuration settings for history server and how to start this?

EDIT 1:

When history server is stopped, all previously recorded information of jobs is deleted. How to retain all those information after cluster and/or history server is restarted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`JobHistoryServer` process has to be started separately.

**To Start:**

```
$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh start historyserver
```

**To Stop:**

```
$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh stop historyserver
```

If the Cluster setup is Pseudo Distributed, no additional properties are required.

In a multinode cluster setup, Add these `JobHistoryServer` properties in `mapred-site.xml`:

```
<property>
   <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.address</name>
   <value>hostname:10020</value> <!-- hostname of machine  where jobhistory service is started -->
</property>
<property>
   <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.address</name>
   <value>hostname:19888</value> 
</property>
```